# Qubes installer not booting

Tags: system-installation, grub2, uefi, qubes

I am currently setting up a Qubes OS in dual boot (I have read the warnings and I know if the issues of doing so) with Windows 10. After having dd'd the latest release disk on a partition of my usb key I tried booting it only to be welcomed by the `grub>` screen. After some searching, I loaded the grub.cfg file to get to the actual grub screen, only to get rejected with an `error:unknown filesystem` error.
I have a recent motherboard with EFI capabilities, so I thought this might help since the new version seemingly supports it: I deactivated the CSM and, when I booted and loaded the grub config file it seemed to do stuff:

```
/EndEntire
filepath:[big string]/File(\EFI\BOOT)
/File(xen.efi)/EndEntire
```

(the screen showed for about less than a second and went back to GRUB's menu). Putting back the CSM I managed to get to that again with an `insmod normal`; in that case, running the command in the grub shell only brought that line and back to `grub>`. To be honest I'm not too sure what the problem seems to be.

FYI: grub itself does recognize the filesystem of the partition in which Qubes is...

Would you guys know what the matter seems to be and how I could get to run it? A year or so back I did it a first time and it was working fine (the key just booted on the installer like it should) but I had to remove it then...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you found a solution to your problem? I am having the same issue.

Comment: AFAIK Qubes OS cannot do UEFI boot (`\EFI\BOOT`), but only legacy boot. So maybe you must enable "legacy boot" in BIOS.